# Selenium click the span below the element I can find

Tags: c#, html, selenium

I am currently trying to create a Selenium framework for the product we are creating at work. I am struggling to find a radio button below:

```
<input type="button" id="f_pAAF60F411E5E4609865C3F6B0923977D45_3_1_0-inputEl" name="boolean_45" data-ref="inputEl" fieldref="PolicyInput.GoingOnCruise" objectref="pAAF60F411E5E4609865C3F6B0923977D" tabindex="0" class="x-form-cb-input x-hidden-clip" autocomplete="off" hidefocus="true" role="radio" aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-checked="false" aria-labelledby="f_pAAF60F411E5E4609865C3F6B0923977D45_3_1_0-boxLabelEl" data-componentid="f_pAAF60F411E5E4609865C3F6B0923977D45_3_1_0">
<span id="f_pAAF60F411E5E4609865C3F6B0923977D45_3_1_0-displayEl" data-ref="displayEl" class="x-form-field x-form-radio x-form-radio-default x-form-cb x-form-cb-default "></span>
```

With the product for me to be able to click the radio but I need to be able to click the span element. However, the problem I am facing is that on the element; `id` is randomly generating per session, `data-ref` and `class` is common with the other random buttons.

The following does not seems to find the span element.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//input[ends-with(@id,'0-inputEl')][@fieldref='PolicyInput.GoingOnCruise']/span")]
private IWebElement CruiseYes;
```

Is there a way to Select the span element. For example, use the `fieldref` from the input element and then use the `0-displayEl` from the span element to then click the span element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following logic:

1. Create a list of all web elements (span) with `data-ref` and `class` attributes.
2. Click on the needed one from the list by index.

Comment: I have got a list of the elements `List<IWebElement> elements = ObjectRepository.Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//span[@data-ref='displayEl']")).ToList();`. how do i click on the first, second, etc?

Comment: `elements[index].click()`, where `index` is an index of the element in your list (index in the list starts from 0). I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following block of code :

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//input[ends-with(@id,'inputEl') and starts-with(@name,'boolean')]/span[@class='x-form-field x-form-radio x-form-radio-default x-form-cb x-form-cb-default']")]
private IWebElement CruiseYes;
```